# How to produce a multiple group bar chart based on a specific dataframe column

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, bar-chart, grouped-bar-chart

I have a dataframe which has the following data:

```
Age A
5   True
5   True
10  False
15  False
15  True
20  False
25  True
```

How can I make a bar chart plot which has the values of the total number of rows in Age? So for example, 7 as the Y axis and the age as the X axis, with each Age having a True/False bar plot.

I would like something like this, however instead of it saying gender F/M, it does True/False, for each Age range:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use [`DataFrame.value_counts()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.value_counts.html) (**pandas > 1.1.0**) or [`SeriesGroupBy.value_counts()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.value_counts.html) (**pandas < 1.1.0**) + [`DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html)

```
df.value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0).plot(kind='bar')
#df.groupby('A')['Age']\
#  .value_counts().unstack(fill_value=0, level=0).plot(kind='bar') # <1.1.0
```

[image]

Also we could use [`seaborn.countplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html#seaborn.countplot)

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.countplot(data=df, x="Age", hue="A")
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Probably your want something like this:

```
count_df = df.groupby("Age").count()
plt.barh(count_df.index, count_df.A, label="False")

sum_df = df.groupby("Age").sum()
plt.barh(sum_df.index, sum_df.A, label="True")

plt.legend()
```

[image]

let me know if I get what you want or i misunderstood your problem.